# Force browser to show a dynamically generated content block immediately without waiting to show all blocks at one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to add **a list of** dynamically generated blocks of content to a page. Generating a block of content takes some time in my case, and so I would like the browser to display a generated block immediately when added without the browser showing ALL generated blocks at one time. Here is how my Javascript code flows in concept:

```
var results = $('#results');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

  var block = Handlebars-generated-content;
  results.append(block);

  var more = = Handlebars-generated-content;
  block.append(more);

}
```

When my page is loaded, the browser is blank initially, a visitor has to wait, and then  all added blocks are displayed at once. I hope the browser can display one block when it is added, so that a visitor can see partial content immediately without waiting longer.

Comment: You could trigger a reflow after each block so you could see stuff as it loads, but if you have a script that takes long enough to freeze a page like that, you might want to consider breaking up the resource-fetching / -rendering into more manageable... blocks.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, while you can force a *reflow* synchronously, you can't force a *redraw*.

Comment: @Kaiido oh, true. I forget that redrawing doesn't occur even if the reflow is done to calculate a style value from a property.

Comment: Patrick and Kaiido, thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is you're using a for loop, which is synchronous; It will run the entire loop, and all subsequent content generations, in a single "frame".

Instead, you should use an "asynchronous loop". This involves making a function and calling it recursively using a zero-millisecond `setTimeout()` after each generation. The timeout gives the browser an opportunity to render so your element will show up sooner.

```js
var items = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
var index = 0;

function asyncLoop() {
  // get our current item based on the index
  var item = items[index];  
  
  // do your work here
  $('#results').append('<ul>' + item + '</ul>');
  
  // increase the index by 1
  index++;
  
  // keep looping if the index isn't at the end yet
  if (index < items.length) {
    // call ourselves using a timeout to give the browser a change to render
    // intentionally set to 500ms to make this more obvious, set it to 0 normally
    setTimeout(asyncLoop, 500);
  }
}

// start the loop
asyncLoop();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="results">
</ul>
```

The only downside to this approach is that doing a single generation per timeout may introduce extra delay between operations since timeouts usually default to minimum of around 4ms on most browsers. To cope with this, you may want to do a small batch of operations per "loop" to optimize the process.

It's also worth noting that this is not threading, just an async loop. The processing will always execute in order, the async aspect simply means it won't process everything all at once.

Comment: While I almost agree with this answer, I also think that the script should be more in general broken up. Like perhaps running handlebars asynchronously (or even in a web-worker, if supported), also fetching the resources via ajax one block at a time, etc.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts then write an answer explaining that. Given the simplicity of the original question, I'm keeping the answer as simple as possible.

Comment: @Soviut, thanks for the solution. One quick question: the order of displayed blocks is important to me. Will your solution produce the garanteed sequence of blocks (as in the array in your example) considering that each block may take different amount of time?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, it's still a loop, not threading. Each iteration calls its next iteration recursively and only after it's finished generating.

Comment: @Soviut you pinged the wrong person. Yes I know it's still a loop :)

Comment: i realized that too late to fix it.